# ng2-pdf-viewer Not rendering files from s3 bucket providing CORS error

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, pdf, amazon-s3, cors

We used ng2-pdf-viewer inside our website.

I able to access below pdf.

```
pdfSrc = "https://vadimdez.github.io/ng2-pdf-viewer/assets/pdf-test.pdf";
```

When I used file url from s3 bucket, we got CORS error.

```
pdfSrc = "https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https%3A%2F%2Fs3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com%2Fdev-facility-ovivo.opsctrl.com%2Fom_media%2Fdummy_1_1680261908.pdf%3FX-Amz-Content-Sha256%3DUNSIGNED-PAYLOAD%26X-Amz-Algorithm%3DAWS4-HMAC-SHA256%26X-Amz-Credential%3DAKIA3S6DCXTNCPEA5NLL%252F20230612%252Feu-west-1%252Fs3%252Faws4_request%26X-Amz-Date%3D20230612T162043Z%26X-Amz-SignedHeaders%3Dhost%26X-Amz-Expires%3D3600%26X-Amz-Signature%3D93ad208dec48da88142fbded31d3596ffa84e4f941881e2629efab77b0d1d5d9&embedded=true"
```

Got Below Error

```
Access to fetch at 'https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https%3A%2F%2Fs3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com%2Fdev-facility-ovivo.opsctrl.com%2Fom_media%2Fdummy_1_1680261908.pdf%3FX-Amz-Content-Sha256%3DUNSIGNED-PAYLOAD%26X-Amz-Algorithm%3DAWS4-HMAC-SHA256%26X-Amz-Credential%3DAKIA3S6DCXTNCPEA5NLL%252F20230612%252Feu-west-1%252Fs3%252Faws4_request%26X-Amz-Date%3D20230612T162043Z%26X-Amz-SignedHeaders%3Dhost%26X-Amz-Expires%3D3600%26X-Amz-Signature%3D93ad208dec48da88142fbded31d3596ffa84e4f941881e2629efab77b0d1d5d9&embedded=true' from origin 'https://devfacility.opsctrl.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

All Cors-related setting enable on s3 bucket.

Using the same link we were able to load same in Iframe.

pdf setting

```
<pdf-viewer 
  [src]="pdfSrc"
  [render-text]="true"
  [original-size]="originalSize"
  [fit-to-page]="fitToPage"
  [zoom]="pdfZoom"
  [(page)]="pdfPageNumber"
  (after-load-complete)="afterLoadComplete($event)"
></pdf-viewer>
```